# Configure Gridsome's webpack dev server to use SSL

Tags: express, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, gridsome

### UPDATE

I ended up [submitting a PR to the gridsome project](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/pull/961) to accomplish what I was trying to do here. Will update this question if it gets accepted. In the meantime you can [view the changes I made](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/compare/master...morphatic:add-dev-ssl-option) in my fork of the project.

### Background

When doing local development, I like to setup SSL to match my production environment as closely as possible. For a typical Vue.js project, I accomplish this as follows:

1. In the root of the project, [install a local certificate](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) with `mkcert example.test`
2. Update my `hosts` file to map `127.0.0.1` (localhost) to `example.test`:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 example.test
```

3. Update the webpack config in `vue.config.js` to use the certificate as follows:

```js
// vue.config.js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      config.devServer = {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        host: 'example.test',
        https: {
          key: fs.readFileSync('./example.test-key.pem', 'utf8'),
          cert: fs.readFileSync('./example.test.pem', 'utf8'),
        },
      }
    }
  },
}
```

With this setup, when I run `npm run serve` I'm able to view my site at https://example.test

### My Goal

I'd like to get a similar configuration setup for a [Gridsome](https://gridsome.org/) project but nothing I've tried so far seems to be taking effect.

### What I've Tried

Here's what I've tried so far that *hasn't* worked:

#### Attempt #1: Update webpack config in `gridsome.config.js`

I tried updating my `gridsome.config.js` file to look as follows:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  siteName: 'Example',
  siteUrl: 'example.test',
  plugins: [],
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      config.devServer = {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        host: 'example.test',
        https: {
          key: fs.readFileSync('./example.test-key.pem', 'utf8'),
          cert: fs.readFileSync('./example.test.pem', 'utf8'),
        },
      }
    }
    return config
  },
}
```

This seemed to have no impact whatsoever.

#### Attempt #2: Update webpack config in `gridsome.server.js`

Likewise I attempted something similar in `gridsome.server.js`:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.configureWebpack({
    devServer: {
      disableHostCheck: true,
      host: 'example.test',
      https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./example.test-key.pem', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./example.test.pem', 'utf8'),
      },
    }
  })
}
```

#### Attempt #3: Modify Express config

[Other people seem to have had similar challenges modifying Gridsome's dev server configuration](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/472). Upon closer inspection, it appears that Gridsome uses [Express](http://expressjs.com/) instead of the internal webpack dev server. Doh! It helps if you're trying to configure the right server. I tried modifying `gridsome.server.js` like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.configureServer(app => {
    // create an HTTPS server
    const server = https.createServer({
      key: fs.readFileSync('./example.test-key.pem', 'utf8'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./example.test.pem', 'utf8'),
    }, app)
    // start it up
    server.listen(8080)
  })
}
```

Although I can confirm this function runs, [Gridsome's internal server config](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/blob/0e82743c3051b2cb1c30fc152492f7ef94d278b5/gridsome/lib/server/Server.js) doesn't appear to include any hooks that would allow something like this to work as I hoped.

### Other Info, Thoughts, etc.

I tried the webpack configuration changes with both the function style, and the object style (like the examples above) in both places. I'm able to get Gridsome to recognize my host by using the flag when I start up the dev server (i.e. `gridsome develop --host example.test`).

My gut feeling is that what I'm trying to do isn't possible. Does anyone know differently? Thank you!!!